# TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration, though still iterating

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm trying to iterate over two arrays while calling a function. The code works somehow for my purposes when I execute it but still get this TypeError.

for i, j in zip(array1, array2):
TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration

I'm afraid this happens because the values of the array are multiplications. As I mentioned above, despite the Error the for loop does iterate over the array. Can somebody help me with this?

```
a1 = [121, 144, 19, 161, 19, 144, 19, 11]
a2 = [11*11, 121*121, 144*144, 19*19, 161*161, 19*19, 144*144, 19*19]


def comp(array1, array2):
# your code
a1, a2 = [], []
for i, j in zip(array1, array2):
    a1.append(i)
    a2.append(j**0.5)
if sum(a1) == sum (a2):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: Please show the part where you actually call the function. Anyway, this has nothing to do with "the values of the array" (actually a list) "being multiplications"; all of that happens ahead of time, and the list doesn't care where its values came from. Also, please make sure that your indentation here matches exactly what you have in the source file; when copying and pasting your source, select the *entire* code block before hitting the indent button.

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the entire code snippet along with your error msg?
Because as far as i know this code should work fine. Check for the intendation maybe.

Comment: You haven't shown the call to `comp`, which is the only way for us to see what non-iterable value is being bound to `array2` inside the call to produce the error message you claim.

Comment: That said, you don't need to compute any square roots. Do `a1.append(i*i)` and `a2.append(j)`, since you don't care about the actually sums, only their relationship to each other.

Comment: Thank everyone, I didn't realize the error arises when calling the function with lists with None values. There was no problem with the lists a1, a2 I posted here. My assumption of where the problem lies was wrong. Thanks again.